# RTL Input in Flash with AS 2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, right-to-left

i'm new to Flash and trying to implement a simple contact form in Flash,

Now when the user is inputting text in hebrew it messes up the order, all the letters are upside down ( Meaning : "this" turns to "siht")
Now i can't move my code to AS3 Because it's implemented in a bigger project that's written in AS2.

**EDIT:**
When this doesn't occur, the words order incorrectly, each word is written before the last word instead of after, any ideas how to fix that too?

All the information about this topic i found is either old or talks about output text.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to intercept the text field's `onChanged` events and manually place the cursor to the left of the newly entered text:

```
myInputField.onChanged = function(field:TextField) { 
    var sel:Number = Selection.getBeginIndex();
    Selection.setSelection (sel-1, sel-1);
};
```

Comment: I have noticed that this happens only when the text field is LTR ( my bad) when it's RTL it just orders the word wrong, each word is written before the last word instead of after, any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to solve a similar task (old project couldn't switch to new components). That problem will get you in a heap of trouble. I recommend strongly to use TLF text fields and AS3, which supports RTL.

No? Let's begin, then:

- the cursor only has to be put on the left if the character was indeed in the RTL unicode  range (easily googleable). Normal characters have to continue floating LTR. And, yes, it can be mixed.
- delete/backspace: should work in reverse around RTL words. a character you just typed should always be deleted witch backspace, after all. which means you have to jump to the other side of a LTR word if you encounter one.
- enter: new line starts at the left. when breaking RTL lines, the left part has to go in the next line, the right part stays. this has to be mirrored for delete/backspace when deleting breaks.
- L/R cursor keys. also reversed.except in LTR words.
- punctuation marks and spaces. they count as RTL after an rtl word, LTR after a LTR one.
- even after all of that, the text will be saved internally in the wrong order. RTL is auto-reverses. which means, you have to scan every text which gets pasted. oh, and the COPY event doesn't work for text fields. so copying from a faked RTL flash text field is strongly discuraged. everything you save or store to a database, you have to reverse. but only the RTL part and its puncuations.